# $lookup target array always empty

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have two tables: `Achievements` and `Achievementcompleteds`

`Achievements` structure: `_id` `title` etc

`Achievementcompleted` structure: `_id` `achievement_id` `user_id`

Now I need to fetch data when `user` is completed achievements and display it with not completed achievements. Theres is a list of achievements and need to show what are completed and what are not completed. I'am trying to do it like this:

```
    Achievement.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "achievementcompleteds", // collection name in db
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "achievement_id",
            as: "completed"
        }
    }
]).then((results) => {});
```

But the completed is always empty

Comment: Have you even checked the output of the `$lookup`? Are there any entries in the `completed` array for any of the documents? Are there any documents that are actually supposed to match from the two collections? Can you show sample documents you expect to match? And can you basically decide which question you are asking here, be it the aggregation result or how to write a template for the working aggregation result.

Comment: Odds are you mean the `$lookup` is not working, and it's probably because the `achievement_id` is actually a "string" whilst the "related" `_id` is of course `ObjectId`. In which case, you need to fix your data.

Comment: It's probably of the ObejctID I never thought of that

Comment: It's almost always the case. The common answer should be much easier to find. Hopefully after a couple of quick edits others find it more easily now as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is perfect. So, you need to check the following issue

1. **achievement_id**: Should be ObjectId
2. **from**: Collection name should be same as collection_name shown in mongodb
3. **Version**: $lookup is available on mongo version 3.4+